# Exp:resso Store Unable to locate file ID Since Upgrading Assets - I Think

Tags: expresso-store, assets

I am seeing this after upgrading Assets to 2.0.5 - it was working perfectly before - I know everyone says that. Environment is EE2.5.5 Store 1.6.3 My template:

```
<tr>
    <th>Order Hash</th>
    <th style="width:14%;">Order ID</th>
    <th style="width:14%;">Order Date</th>
    <th style="width:14%;">Items</th>
    <th style="width:14%;">Total</th>
    <th style="width:14%;">Status</th>
    <th style="width:14%;">Download</th>

</tr>
{exp:store:orders member_id='CURRENT_USER' secure="yes" order_by='order_date' sort='desc'}

{if no_orders}
    <tr class="product_detail">
        <td colspan="4">Sorry, no matching orders were found.</td>
    </tr>
{/if}
    <tr class="product_detail">
        <td>{order_hash}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><a class="onwhite" href="{path='products/order/{order_hash}'}">{order_id}</a></td>
        <td>{order_date format="%d/%m/%y %H:%m"}</td>
        <td>{items}{title}<br />{/items}</td>
        <td>{order_total}</td>
        <td>{order_status}</td>
        <td>
            {exp:store:download order_id="{order_id}" url="{software}" class="onwhite"}
                Download
            {/exp:store:download}
        </td>
    </tr>

{/exp:store:orders}
```

The file is visible in the EE file manager. This appears to be different from question 769 since it was working before, but stopped after upgrading Assets. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: There shouldn't be any link between an upgrade to Assets and Store so it's either a coincidence or the upgrade to Assets has caused a problem in the system which needs to be resolved first. What's the exact error you're getting and where? Is it just not returning anything at all?

Comment: The only error is a Store error - "Unable to locate file ID"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem turned out to be due to a database corruption that occurred during one of the software upgrades, most likely the Store upgrade. Since I corrected that, all is well again.

Comment: That old chestnut. Unfortunately they happen from time to time. Glad your got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be an issue if you have uploaded the file via the native file browser from upgrading Assets. Try changing your template to the following:

```
<tr>
    <th>Order Hash</th>
    <th style="width:14%;">Order ID</th>
    <th style="width:14%;">Order Date</th>
    <th style="width:14%;">Items</th>
    <th style="width:14%;">Total</th>
    <th style="width:14%;">Status</th>
    <th style="width:14%;">Download</th>

</tr>

    {exp:store:orders member_id='CURRENT_USER' secure="yes" order_by='order_date' sort='desc'}

    {if no_orders}
        <tr class="product_detail">
            <td colspan="4">Sorry, no matching orders were found.</td>
        </tr>
    {/if}
        <tr class="product_detail">
            <td>{order_hash}</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><a class="onwhite" href="{path='products/order/{order_hash}'}">{order_id}</a></td>
            <td>{order_date format="%d/%m/%y %H:%m"}</td>
            <td>{items}{title}<br />{/items}</td>
            <td>{order_total}</td>
            <td>{order_status}</td>
            <td>
      {items}
                {exp:store:download order_id="{order_id}" url="{software}" class="onwhite"}
                    Download
                {/exp:store:download}
      {/items}
            </td>
        </tr>

    {/exp:store:orders}
```

This should allow Store to know which item to generate the downloads for.

Comment: Justin - thank you for your suggestion, but it makes no difference.  FWIW, the Assets upgrade also seems to have had another effect on the EE file system, which is to prevent file manipulations from working. I originally reported these effects in a single question, but decided to separate them in case they were in fact a coincidence. I am waiting to hear from P&T about the other effect. Since it does not involve Store, it might be easier to isolate.

Comment: You can also add a channel entries tag so you have `{items}{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}{exp:store:download ....}Download{/exp:store:download}{/exp:channel:entries}{/items}` In some environments this can also help fix the problem.

Comment: Hi Justin - I have tried both ways. Without the channel entries tags, I get the "Unable to locate file_id" error. If I  use the channel entries tags, the URL renders multiple times, one for each downloadable product. What is worse, it assigns them all to every paid order regardless of whether the order included the product or not!!

Comment: I am wondering why the Store manual does not mention the channel entries tags? Whatever the case, it is now clear that for whatever reason, bug or not, the URL does not render unless the entries tags are used, and when they are used, they are rendered regardless of the order to which they are attached. Still hoping that I am just doing something wrong.

Comment: I did not notice this before because I was fixated on the download link, but the title is also missing from the display. This seems to make it clear that the channel entries tags are required, but even if I use them, I am still left with the fact that Store is not tying the order item to the channel entry.

Comment: This has to be a bug - the example my_orders.html template distributed with Store V1.6.3 for DOES NOT USE the channel entries tags. When I use the example template code, {item_qty} renders but {title} does not. I need help.

Comment: Following up - when I enclose the {exp:store:orders …} tag in EE channel entries tag for the channel involved, I get two different reuslts:

- for existing orders, I get all orders/downloadable files regardles of whether they were ordered or not, for any logged-in user.

- newly-entered orders work correctly

Comment: If you have user that are not members of your site you should not use `member_id='CURRENT_USER'` in the opening form tag. You would be better off using `order_hash="{segment_X}` with X being the segment that had the order hash in it.

Comment: Justin - I need some help with your suggestion. A customer comes to the site and wants to download software purchased previously - this is not a one-time-only kind of purchase. The Customer has bought a number of different software items via a number of different orders, meaning different order hashes. How can I use the order hash only without having the customer ID in such a case?

Comment: If the user does not have a member account then the only way to access their data is via the order_hash (which you would want to send them via email) They would need to go to each specific order_hash to get the software purchased with the corresponding order. If a user creates an account either before or during checkout you can use the template as you have. "CURRENT_USER" only counts for logged in members guest would have a value of "0" I do believe